# Sklearn.svm.LinearSVC is inconsistent, often times it only predicts for 1 of 4 results alone and others times more, rarely does it predict for all 4

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, classification, svc

- I have been working with this custom dataset that is supposed to predict out of 4 possibilities (A, B, C, D).
- The training and the test dataset contains an even amount of each of the 4 possible results.
- This dataset is then passed to a sklearn.svm.LinearSVC() model to predict.
- For some reason most of the time I run the model on the test dataset I often get reports which are either predicting the same result exclusively or at best not predicting one of the results at all while the rest of the predictions are spread evenly.
- Rarely (one in 3ish) do I get a report where (as it should) the predictions are spread evenly amongst all the 4 results.

```
X = trainer.drop(['TResult'], axis = 1)
y = trainer['TResult']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
newModel = LinearSVC()
newModel.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = newModel.predict(X_test)
rep = classification_report(y_test, pred)
print(rep)
```

Report/Run 1:

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          A       0.00      0.00      0.00        56   <Nothing here
          B       0.00      0.00      0.00        79   <Nothing here
          C       0.24      1.00      0.38        66
          D       0.00      0.00      0.00        78   <Nothing here

avg / total       0.06      0.24      0.09       279
```

Report/Run 2:

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          A       0.20      0.18      0.19        65
          B       0.32      0.17      0.22        78    ]expected
          C       0.22      0.59      0.32        51
          D       0.50      0.26      0.34        85

avg / total       0.33      0.28      0.27       279
```

Report/Run 3:

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          A       0.32      0.75      0.45        67
          B       0.00      0.00      0.00        79   <Nothing here
          C       0.00      0.00      0.00        68   <Nothing here
          D       0.33      0.62      0.43        65

avg / total       0.15      0.32      0.21       279
```

Report/Run 4:

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          A       0.23      0.08      0.12        59
          B       0.24      0.75      0.36        69
          C       0.00      0.00      0.00        73   <Nothing here
          D       0.39      0.21      0.27        78

avg / total       0.22      0.26      0.19       279
```

Report/Run 5:

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          A       1.00      0.02      0.03        66
          B       0.25      0.73      0.38        63    ]expected
          C       0.60      0.04      0.08        71
          D       0.37      0.43      0.40        79

avg / total       0.55      0.30      0.23       279
```

Comment: Assuming nothing is wrong with your code or data, the linear model is not converging. Try `svm.SVC()` with a nonlinear kernel such as radial-basis function or polynomial kernel, if you want to stick with SVM's. Also, remember that SVM's generally require standardising the data before training, such as with `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()`

Comment: So you are training the model again and again on different set of train and test data?